# How to get href with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

**The Situation**

I want to **scrape** from this website:
http://www.dpm.tn/dpm_pharm/medicament/listmedicparnomspec.php

**My code:**

```py
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    # agent
    user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36"

    # headless driver
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.headless = True
    options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    options.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'")
    options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*")
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\Downloads\chromedriver.exe", options=options)

    # request test
    medecine = 'doliprane'

    # submiting a search
    driver.get('http://www.dpm.tn/dpm_pharm/medicament/listmedicparnomspec.php')
    e = driver.find_element_by_name('id')
    e.send_keys(medecine)
    e.submit()

    # geting the result table
    try:
        table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody')
        print('succes')
    except:
        print('failed')
```

The code to get the link :

```py
    print('bs4 turn \n')
        result = BeautifulSoup(table.get_attribute('innerHTML'), 'lxml')
    
        rows = result.find_all('tr')
    links = []
    real_link = []
    for row in rows:
       links.append(row.find('a', href= True))
    for each in links:
       print(each['href'])
```

**The Problem:**

Whenever running this I always get this error:
`'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

**The question:**

How can I get this and find the href attribute as required?

Comment: From looking at the link you posted above this would be because you are looking for an element that is not within the page

Comment: @Kwsswart its in the page if i print the elements of links it will return all the a tags but if i want to get the links from href it returns this error bellow

Comment: Have you tried instead of appending the whole a to the list within the for row in rows collect the href immediately and then append it to the list?

Comment: yes it works but it returns the hole a tag not the link

Comment: There is something like `.get['href']`

Comment: Try this https://dpaste.com/AVXR4LS92

Comment: A previous one I had done worked with this format https://dpaste.com/3E5BQSXGY

Comment: @Kwsswart neither of them worked :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using selenium use the requests library and fetch data and parse it.

Code:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

medecine = 'doliprane'
url = "http://www.dpm.tn/dpm_pharm/medicament/listmedicspec.php"
payload = {"id":medecine}
response = requests.post(url, data=payload)
parsedhtml=BeautifulSoup(response.content,"html.parser")
regex = re.compile('fiche.php.*')
atag=parsedhtml.findAll("a",{"href":regex})
links =[i['href'].replace("fiche.php","http://www.dpm.tn/dpm_pharm/medicament/fiche.php") for i in atag ]
print(links)
```

Let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: sorry but just one detail i just want to get the links of details not all of them like the ones coming from notice. How can I do that I've tried but I cant :(

Comment: check the above answer I have updated it to fetch only details link.

Answer (score 0):

When accessing it try with:

```
    print('bs4 turn \n')
    result = BeautifulSoup(table.get_attribute('innerHTML'), 'lxml')
    
    rows = result.find_all('tr')
    links = []
    real_link = []
    for row in rows:
       a = row.find("a", href=True)
       links.append(a['href'])
    for each in links:
       print(each)
```

Comment: sorry but it didn't work. it shows the same error

Answer (score 0):

I solved it but using selenium instead of Beautiful soup:

```
    for i in range(2, max):
        a_driver = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[{i}]/td[11]/a')

        result2 = BeautifulSoup(a_driver.get_attribute('innerHTML'), 'lxml')

        link = a_driver.get_attribute('href')
        links.append(link)

    for i in range(0, len(links)):
        print(links[i])
```

this is worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be related to how you're trying to locate the a elements in your rows. Here's a suggestion on how you can modify your code to properly extract the links:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Your existing code for setting up the driver and submitting the search goes here...

# After you get the result table using Selenium
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody')

# Convert the table HTML to BeautifulSoup object
result = BeautifulSoup(table.get_attribute('innerHTML'), 'lxml')

# Find all rows in the result table
rows = result.find_all('tr')

# Initialize a list to store the links
links = []

# Iterate through rows to find links
for row in rows:
    link = row.find('a', href=True)
    if link:
        links.append(link['href'])

# Print the extracted links
for link in links:
    print(link)
```